# Forward Error Correction for WAN optimization

Tags: linux, wide-area-network, packetloss

Anyone know of user-space tools providing forward error correction with/for tunnelling a stream over UDP on Linux?

I found [Trafficsqueezer](http://www.trafficsqueezer.org/), [utunnel](http://www.thebends.org/~allen/utunnel/) and [toutunnel](http://code.google.com/p/toutunnel/) which implement TCP over UDP, but none seem to provide Forward Error Control.

(for the benefit of those browsing through these questions, not familiar with WAN optimization: Limit on Bandwidth = `MSS/(RTT*SQRT(p))` where SQRT(p) is the square root of the packet loss)

Comment: Well, fec is easy to do yourself, but it's not really good for WAN, but for e.g. satellite broadcast, where single packets are dropped. In WAN, there are either bitrate drops, or few second to few minutes outages, depends how far you are streaming. Check out STCP, it does good job, but for WAN the best is to use proper TCP with rateshaping you do yourself and RT Linux. So you encapsulate in TCP, and when making it UDP again, you need to rateshape it. You need to go zigzag on WAN using TCP. For rateshaping Redhat MRG (centos) is very good.

Comment: Simply FEC doesnt work for WAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UDPSpeeder**

One that showed up on HN recently was [UDPSpeeder](https://github.com/wangyu-/UDPspeeder) and may have what you were looking for.  UDPSpeeder implements FEC.  Apologies for answering several years late.

Comment: I'll accept that as an answer (I ended up using udpcast with a TCP control channel)